# Array to String Conversion in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, implode

This is my sample JSON data that I need to implode. During that time I'm getting an array to string conversion error.

**JSON**

```
{
"user_id" :"110" ,
"parent_id": "115",
"relation_name" : "justin",
"data" :[
{"relation_ship": "brohter"},   
{"relation_ship": "sister"}
],
"sum_assured": "89745$-$48721",
"annual_primium":"00000$-$0006557",
"paid_status" : "0$-$1",
"ins_company_name" : "yes",
"renew_date": "2018-10-11$-$2018-10-23"
}
```

Here is my function for imploding, please help me fix this.

```php
<?php

if (isset($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $data_insert['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $data_insert['parent_id'] = $user_id;
        $data_insert['relation_name'] = $data['relation_name'];
        $data_insert['relation_ship'] = implode("$-$", $data['data']);
        $data_insert['sum_assured'] = implode("$-$", $data['sum_assured']);
        $data_insert['annual_primium'] = implode("$-$", $data['annual_primium']);
        $data_insert['paid_status'] = implode("$-$", $data['paid_status']);
        $data_insert['renew_date'] = implode("$-$", $data['renew_date']);
        $data_insert['ins_company_name'] = implode("$-$", $data['ins_company_name']);
        DB::table('health_tbl')->insert($data_insert);
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'Success', 'message' => 'Success']);
}

return response()->json(['status' => 'Failure', 'message' => 'Failed']);
```

Comment: why are you imploding "data" :[
{"relation_ship": "brohter"},   
{"relation_ship": "sister"}
], on $-$

Comment: to save in single field

Comment: I think your don't understand your structure, 
Is  $data your json? 
If yes, then why the field relation_ship has two values?

Comment: Debug your "$value" at you foreach,
just print_r($value) and comment all the lines with $data_insert, maybe you could see whats is wrong

Comment: @karl Hill If user clicks add moew details i need to store in single field so that relationship field has two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't implode something that isn't an array.  Implode is basically used to turn something like this:

```php
array('something', 'something else')
```

Into something like this:

```php
implode('<delim>', array('something', 'something else')) => "something<delim>something else"
```

Are you intending on exploding them to tear them into their own arrays?

In that case, use explode like this:

```php
explode('$-$', $data['paid_status']);
```

That would return (using your data above):

```php
array("0", "1")
```

Comment: tnx for u r answer FYI that works but if i send only one data for each field , is there any other way to store two json datas in single field

Comment: You'll have to use a delimeter of your own.  You'll often find that Laravel uses the pipe character ("|") pretty often as a delimeter.